# .htaccess redirect to sub folder works occassionally

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site which runs from a sub directory - hosted on HostGator. Most of the htaccess rules work to redirect to the sub directory except for one.

if i go to example.com/products - I get an invisible redirect to example.com/subfolder/products - it appears correctly in the address bar as example.com/products

however if i go to example.com/news - I get a visible redirect to example.com/subfolder/news - it appears in the address bar incorrectly as example.com/subfolder/news

The following is the .htaccess code I am using in my root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /subfolder/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

For reference: If I type example.com/news into the browser I am visibly redirected to example.com/subfolder/news - however if I type example.com/news into the browser a second time I am invisibly redirected!

Google has crawled the site and is serving the visible redirect urls (so they appear in Google as example.com/subfolder/news)

UPDATE:

In that `.htaccess` file the only other line I have it `Options -Indexes`

In the **subfolder** `.htaccess` file I also have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/403
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/500
```

I'm with HostGator if that would have any bearing?

Comment: Sounds like your `.htaccess` is occasionally serving a `301` redirect. Do you have any other code in your `.htaccess` or other `.htaccess` files that might cause this?

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache. None of your code would create a redirect, so perhaps it is an redirect generated by previous some code, that is cached.

Comment: Scott, I was talking with a friend, and he suggested it might be a trailing slash problem. Having added the trailing slash typing the URL worked 100% of the time, but I'm worried that Google etc will fail without the trailing slash. Is there anything I can do about that?